# Setting a boolean value based on an integer

Tags: c#, coding-style, readability

I found this statement is some old code and it took me a second to figure out...

```
IsTestActive = (TestStateID == 1 ? true : false);
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong but isn't this the same as this one?:

```
IsTestActive = (TestStateID == 1);
```

If it is, why would you ever want to use the first?  Which one is more readable? (I think the latter, but I'd like to see what others think.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it is exactly the same.

Yes, the latter is more readable.

Comment: I've only seen the former used by 2 types of people: those who lack a fundamental understanding of boolean logic, or those that think the ternary operator is really cool.

Comment: The former would theoretically have a minute perf hit, though if you're caring about that level of performance then I suspect you have bigger problems...

Answer (score 5):

```
IsTestActive = (TestStateID == 1);
```

is definitely more readable.

You *could* make a case for defining a constant

```
ACTIVE = 1
```

then replacing the boolean variable `IsTestActive` with

```
(TestStateID == ACTIVE)
```

The way the code is now, the state of the boolean `IsTestActive` will be erroneous if the state of `TestStateID` changes without updating the boolean.  Bypassing the boolean and testing the real source of the information you're after will remove the possibility of this error.

Comment: good point, I hate magic integers - but I assume the OP was just posting example code

Comment: That may be, but I do see a lot of people using temp variables like this in production code.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no practical reason for using the first version, world isn't perfect, [and neither are programmers.](http://thedailywtf.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Readability depends on where you use this construct. I often find something like

```
(TestStateID == 1 ? true : false)
```

more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know about other languages, but in PHP it's even more easy, using type-casting:

```
$IsTestActive = (boolean)$TestStateId;
```